# Datagridview connection from code to form designer

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I've been following C#station's ADO.net tutorials today and I've gotten to the datagrid example (http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson05) which has a datagrid built behind the designer, in the form.cs file programmatically.

Do I have to use the server explorer to connect to my SQL Server using the wizard before it will allow me to drag a DatagridView from the toolbox and use it? I'd like to design my Form without messing around with padding ect. in the .cs file

Thanks,
Ross

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to, but any data provider needs configuration data to retrieve it, so if you don't use the wizard, you'll have to set them manually.

Answer (score 0):

You will simply have to use the connection string to your SQL Server instance when you create the SQLConnection object in your code.

```
public void Initdata()
{
// instantiate the connection
conn = new SqlConnection([YourConnectionString]);   
}
```

For testing purposes this can be hardcoded in as in the example the tutorial gives, but it is a best practice to store your database connection strings in a config file and then reference the config at runtime. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) article on connection strings.